# Installing scikit learn onto windows 8

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda

So, I have been having a problem with importing the sci-kit learn modules into my python code after having installing it through Anaconda.  Apparently, Anaconda basically has everything you need to run scikit learn within its whole package.  I am new to python, and I need to become familiar with sci kit learn, however as I said before, the "import sklearn" statement in my python code is simply not doing anything.  I also have windows 8. Does anyone have any suggestions they would not mind telling me?  I installed using conda by the way, and it says that scipy, numpy, and scikit learn are all installed, and I am using python 3.6  Thank you

Comment: What kind of error messages are you getting?

Comment: Thank you for replying!  Actually, when I try to compile and run my code in Microsoft Visual Studio, I now get an error that says : Module use of python36.dll conflicts with this version of Python.  So, trying to figure out why sklearn is not working with python 3.4 I suppose.